# Java function graph with applet

Tags: java, graph, applet

how I can draw this function graph in java with applet:

```
f(x)=ax^3+bsin(x)
```

I try this:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Graph extends Applet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
    {
        double a=70;
        double n=450;
        int x;
        int y;
        for (int  i=0; i<n+1;i++) 
        {
            x=(int) ((int) (a*i*i*i)+(n*Math.sin(i)));
            y=(int) ((int) (a*i*i*i)+(n*Math.sin(i)));
            g.drawLine(0,0,x,y);}
        }
    }
}
```

But I got a line

Comment: applets are dead technology

Comment: It's for science.

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). *"It's for science"*  Swing and a desktop application (e.g. based on `JFrame`) can also be used for science. More relevant, they will work in the current day and many more people would be able to assist when there are problems. 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for ..

Comment: .. many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.